# I want to install wine with easiest way

Tags: wine

I want to install wine on Ubuntu and I'm new to Ubuntu, but tutorials on the internet are so hard for me is there any easier way

Comment: What do you mean with "hard"? The tutorials online are --all--  copy/paste so that is not difficult to do. The problem is getting games to work in wine as this involves knowing how wine works. I would suggest to install windows (as a dual boot or inside Ubuntu) and game from there :)

Comment: Yes you are right but I don't know much about terminal too also I just want it for some basic apps

Comment: then wine will not be a thing for you... it is riddled with text editing configurations

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is but you will get an older version of wine

Just open terminal and type

`sudo apt install wine`

It will install wine but it asks few questions and you should answer with yes or no

Comment: I typed it on terminal and it's downloading now , thanks !